# Call of Duty: Black Ops Zombies on iPod Missing textures

Tags: ios, cod-black-ops-zombies-mobile

I recently bought Call of Duty: Black Ops Zombies on the Apple App Store on my iPod fifth-generation that uses iOS8. But when I loaded the game there were no textures - it was all primarily black and white X shaped blotches aside from the character tank Dempsey in the tutorial. The main menu also only had words and a whole bunch of little squares with no colored like it should have.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a developer issue not your iPod. The app has been stagnant since January 2014 and no updates since then. The reviews display the same woes you do. They obviously have not optimized it for the new devices or updated it for iOS 8 since that came out later in the year. It's simply nothing within your control. You can submit feedback to them to encourage iOS 8 compliance. Other than that all you can do is wait. Clearly a developer issue.

[image: reviews]

Comment: Thanks for the info I guess I forgot to read the reviews

Answer (score 0):

Go to iTunes, click on versions. Make sure your iPod is connected to the Internet and your computer. Click on any version instead of All iOS8 versions.